# hadoop pipeline write and rack awareness

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, rack, pipeline

When each file is written into the cluster, the HDFS will create a replication pipeline. Assume there are two racks 1 and 5. According to rack awareness, the first block will be saved into rack 1, and the the other two replicated blocks will be pushed into rack 5.

I am very confused that why hadoop pipeline will store the second and third replicated blocks in the same rack (5) rather than store the first and second blocks in the same rack (1)? Both two scenarios have same network traffic. What's the advantage of it?

Thanks.

Please refer to this figure http://bradhedlund.s3.amazonaws.com/2011/hadoop-network-intro/HDFS-Pipleline-Write-s.png

Answer (score 0):

This applies to HDFS 1.2   The reason that both blocks are put on the remote rack is to minimize the inter rack traffic.  Since the second block is already on the remote rack, copying the block between two servers on the remote rack will not consume the bandwidth of the link between the racks.  If the top of the rack switch of efficient design this will minimize the bandwidth utilization to minimum.   On a busy cluster the same process will be happening on both racks.  Where rack A and rack B will generate blocks roughly at the same rate.  So, following this policy helps to even out bandwidth utilization of all the links.

Comment: Thanks~ But according to official document http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html, it says "For the common case, when the replication factor is three, HDFS’s placement policy is to put one replica on one node in the local rack, another on a node in a different (remote) rack, and the last on a different node in the same remote rack."

Comment: Seems like 1.2 changed the block distribution policy.  I corrected my answer.